# Two UITableViews in one scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to make `UIViewController`, which has 2 `UITableViews` - one is content tableview, second is an comments section tableview.

Basically, It's an detail product VC, which has own `UITableView` for own content and second `UITableView` will be CommentsVC tableview.

Problem is that, I want to get them like one whole tableView (scroll together) (like 2 section style).

My first idea was to create `UIScrollView` container, which contains both `UITableViews`, but I think that there will be problem with reusing cells.

[Example sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvagS.png)

Comment: Exactly what do you want please elaborate in brief. So we can help you in proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you take tableview inside scrollview it creates problem in scrolling i.e conflicting scrolls of both scrollview and tableview as **`UIScrollview` is superview of `UITableView`** .

So it's better to take one `UITableView` with different section. One Section for your content and another section for comments.

Comment: Ok, tnx for feedback ;) I think i will go with this approach.

Comment: what if the child section item contains one more tableview?